# Python break deep recursion - 2.7.8

Tags: python, recursion, break

So I have a huge recursive function. At some point, it finds a result, and I need it to stop all functions. Suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Show us your code.

Comment: I can't show you all of the code, it's huge. Isn't there some way to break all the recursion?

Comment: Then show us the general pattern the code is following. Surely, somewhere you return either the final result or some "not found"-type, like None, and somewhere you do a recursive call. Probably you have to check the result of the recursive call and either return the result or try again. But with not clue of what your function looks like it's impossible to help.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to refactor it into smaller functions to make it more compact?

Comment: Okay so the function finds a special string, and in that string it finds a lot of other strings. At some point it finds the correct string, and I just made a simple if string == rightstring, then print I found it. That's what it currently does, but it keeps on going after finding the correct string. I want to terminate all instances of the function. Is this possible?

Comment: Do not just `print` inside your recursive function! Instead, `return` the result, and keep `return`ing it in the "outer" function calls until you pop it off the stack. _Then_ print it.

Comment: So there's no terminate-all-instances-of-function function?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that can break out of multiple levels of indentation is `raise`, but it's really not intended to be used this way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cannot refactor your code, you could use generators to achieve this. Let's say we have the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def g(n):
    print("g before", n)
    if n < 3:
        for i in g(n+1):
            yield i
    else:
        yield n
    print("g after", n)
```

The normal execution would be:

```
>> for i in g(0):
...     print(i)
...
g before 0
g before 1
g before 2
g before 3
3
g after 3
g after 2
g after 1
g after 0
```

Now what you want is to yield 3 and stop right there, so we just fetch the first value:

```
>>> print(g(0).__iter__().next())
g before 0
g before 1
g before 2
g before 3
3
```